# how can realize openssl pkeyutl -sign by java

Tags: java, openssl, rsa, sign

the command line is

```
openssl pkeyutl   -sign -inkey pkcs1.pem -pkeyopt digest:sha1  -in testlog
```

I want to realize it by java.
But NONEwithRSA or SHA1withRSA neither give the same output.
the NONEwithRSA's output is the same with

```
openssl pkeyutl   -sign -inkey pkcs1.pem   -in testlog
```

which has no **-pkeyopt digest:sha1**

the java code just like

```
 Signature sign = Signature.getInstance(algorithm);
 sign.initSign(privatekey);
 sign.update(keyByte);
 return sign.sign();
```

I don't know how to amend this.

thank's very much

What I really want to do is to implement the C function by Java

```
RSA_sign(NID_sha1, token, token_size, sig, &len, key->rsa)
```

which dose not hash the Plaintext

https://github.com/usb4java/usb4java-javax-examples/blob/97b95c80e8af87f935f736ed7b4f4a197d4643ac/src/main/java/org/usb4java/javax/examples/adb/Adb.java
This can meet my needs.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're claiming but I get the same output using Java and the openssl command line you've shown. My guess is that you are neglecting to hash the input prior to supplying it to `pkeyutl`. `pkeyutl` performs no hashing, whereas Java's Signature class does.

Comment: I don't want to hash the input. just want to signature the Plaintext itself, no hash it .
Dose your command has '-pkeyopt digest:sha1' ?

Comment: What I actually want to do is to achieve the function in C 

RSA_sign(NID_sha1, token, token_size, sig, &len, key->rsa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openssl pkeyutl -sign` with an RSA private key and `-pkeyopt digest:$alg` does steps 2-5 of [EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2) plus the private modexp (i.e. 8.2.1 step 2 using RSASP1 from 5.2.1); without that `-pkeyopt` it does not do step 2, which encodes the hash value in a simple ASN.1 structure.

The Java `Signature` algorithms that include a hash like `SHA1withRSA` do *all* steps of EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5 plus modexp, while the scheme `NONEwithRSA` does only steps 3-5 plus modexp, and neither of these matches what you want. If you can't supply the data to let `Signature` do the hashing, you'll need to **do step 2 yourself** and *then* `NONEwithRSA`. Although ASN.1 encoding in general can be complicated (and decoding even more so), this case can be done simply **by  concatenating a prefix determined entirely by the hash algorithm to the hash value**; see note 1 on page 47.

Meta: there have been *lots* of Qs about the differences in RSA v1_5 signatures between openssl `rsautl`, `pkeyutl` with and without `-pkeyopt digest`, or `dgst -sign` and other systems like Java, all to do with the issue of including or not including the ASN.1 encoding step (and many of them older than rfc8017!) but I can't find any that is a good dupe for this Q.

Comment: thanks, add the header to the data is correct. 
sha1: 30 21 30 09 06 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a 05 00 04 14